# Does VSCode C/C++ Intellisense complete members of class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I am trying out VSCode C/C++ intellisense extension by Microsoft.

When I instantiate a Foo class

```
Foo foo;
```

and then type

```
foo.
```

It does not complete with public members from class foo. Is this shortcoming to be expected or have I got something configured incorrectly.

What it does suggest in the case seems to be like very symbol from the entire workspace, and nothing specific to foo class.

Is this a known limitation? Is it a planned feature in future releases?

my c_cpp_properties.json is as follows...

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                    "${workspaceFolder}"
                ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
            },
            "includePath": [
                **REDACTED**
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "compilerPath": "C:\\AndroidTools\\android-ndk-r13b\\toolchains\\llvm\\prebuilt\\windows-x86_64\\bin\\clang.exe",
            "intelliSenseMode": "clang-x64",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

Comment: have you followed the instructions: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp sounds like you are ending up with the tag parser

Comment: VS code C++ extension does support intellisense but its limited to certain extent. You will not get complete intellisense features like how we have in Visual studio. At the end of the day VS code is just an editor not an IDE. For intellisense configuration in VS Code, you can follow these instructions:- https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/Documentation/Getting%20started%20with%20IntelliSense%20configuration.md

Comment: Based on the two links provided in the comments, I am correctly configured and the include paths are properly resolved.